# How to avoid "surf error X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex"

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure, figure

I've already tried to change `x`, `y`, `z` but it still does not work.

The error said that there is problem in

> (line 72) surf(t/sigma,x*sqrt(P/sigma)/sqrt(phi),abs(Y(:,1:M)));

My full code is:

```
clc
M = input ('M = ');
N = input ('N = ');
epsilon = input ('epsilon = ');
dx = 0.01;
dt = 2.5000e-005;
x0 = -N/2*dx;
r = dt/dx^2;
D = 0.1*1.6e5;
mass=5.1e-13;
a=3e-2;
k=24;
K=8;
l=340;
lambda=10*1;
q=2*pi/lambda;
h=4;
sigma=1e10;
tau=0;
e2=0.001;
wg = 2*a*sqrt(D/mass);
w = sqrt(wg+(2*k*(1-cos(q*1))+2*K*(cos(q*l*h)+1))/mass);
Vg=(1*(k*sin(1*q)-K*h*sin(l*q*h))/(mass*w));
alfa = (-3*a)/sqrt(2);
beta = 7*a^2/3;
miu=-2*alfa/(1+4*K/ (mass*wg.^2));
delta=(wg.^2)*alfa/(4*w^2+2*k*(cos(2*q*1-1)/mass-2*K*(cos(2*h*q*l)+1)/mass-wg^2));
P=(((1^2)*(k*cos(1*q)-K*(h^2)*cos(l*q*h))/mass)-Vg^2)/(2*w);
Q=(-wg.^2*(2*alfa*(miu+delta)+3*beta)/(2*w));
phi= 0.0005;
psi=0.03;
F=zeros(N,M);
Y=zeros(N,M);
 for n=1:N
    x(n,1)=x0+(n-1)*dx;
    F(n,1)=((sqrt(2)/psi)*sech(x(n,1))/sqrt(phi));
  end

%running program
 for m=1:M
  for n=2:N-1
     if n==2
        F(n-1,m)=3*F(n,m)-3*F(n+1,m)+F(n+2,m);
     end
     if n==N-1
        F(n+1,m)=3*F(n,m)-3*F(n-1,m)+F(n-2,m);
     end
    
     if m==1
        F(n,m+1)=1i*((phi^2*r*(F(n+1,m)-2*(F(n,m))+F(n-1,m))+(psi^2*dt*(conj(F(n,m))*(F(n,m)^2))+F(n,m))));
     else
        F(n,m+1)=2*1i*((phi^2*r*(F(n+1,m)-2*(F(n,m))+F(n-1,m))+(psi^2*dt*(conj(F(n,m))*(F(n,m)^2))+F(n,m-1))));
     end
 t(m) = (m-1)*dt;
 theta(n,m)=(n*q*l)-(w*t(m)/e2);
 Y(n,m) = ((e2*(psi*F(n,m)/(sqrt(Q/sigma))))*(2*(cos((sigma*tau)+theta(n,m)))))+((e2^2*((psi*F(n,m)/(sqrt(Q/sigma)))^2))*(miu+(2*delta*(cos(2*((sigma*tau)+theta(n,m)))))));
 end

%grafik 3 dimensi
figure
surf(t/sigma,x*sqrt(P/sigma)/sqrt(phi),abs(Y(:,1:M)));
view(0,90);
colorbar
shading interp
xlabel ('T');
ylabel ('x');
zlabel ('y');

%grafik hubungan Y terhadap x
figure
plot((x*sqrt(P/sigma)),abs(Y(:,0)));
xlabel ('x(pm)');
ylabel ('Y(pm)');

figure
plot((x*sqrt(P/sigma)),abs(Y(:,M)));
xlabel ('x(pm)');
ylabel ('Y(pm)');
```

It makes the figure not shown. Please what should I do?

Comment: Try adding real to the second argument as so: `surf(t/sigma,real(x*sqrt(P/sigma)/sqrt(phi)),abs(Y(:,1:M)));` Also seems like the matrix dimensions might not agree though.

Comment: after i did what you recommend to me there is more problem "Error in edo24 (line 82)
plot((real(x*sqrt(P/sigma))),abs(Y(:,0)));

Comment: after that what should id do?

Comment: MATLAB indexing begins at 1 so change the line to `plot((real(x*sqrt(P/sigma))),abs(Y(:,1)));`

Comment: Do you have any example input values I can use to test the script?

Comment: M=10000
N=200
epsilon=1

Comment: It runs without any error after those two adjustments but the plot seems not to be correct, but of course, I'm not sure of the use case or context. There might be a need for a closing `end` for the nested for-loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Taking Real Components and MATLAB Indexing

To avoid errors referring to imaginary components add the `real()` function to only use the real components while surface plotting:

```
surf(t/sigma,real(x*sqrt(P/sigma)/sqrt(phi)),abs(Y(:,1:M)));
```

---

MATLAB indexing begins at "1" rather than the "0" that many languages use. Changing `abs(Y(:,0))` to `abs(Y(:,1))` may sole the problem.

```
plot((real(x*sqrt(P/sigma))),abs(Y(:,1)));
```

---

Adding additional `end` to close the nested for-loop.

```
 for m=1:M
  for n=2:N-1
     if n==2
        F(n-1,m)=3*F(n,m)-3*F(n+1,m)+F(n+2,m);
     end
     if n==N-1
        F(n+1,m)=3*F(n,m)-3*F(n-1,m)+F(n-2,m);
     end
    
     if m==1
        F(n,m+1)=1i*((phi^2*r*(F(n+1,m)-2*(F(n,m))+F(n-1,m))+(psi^2*dt*(conj(F(n,m))*(F(n,m)^2))+F(n,m))));
     else
        F(n,m+1)=2*1i*((phi^2*r*(F(n+1,m)-2*(F(n,m))+F(n-1,m))+(psi^2*dt*(conj(F(n,m))*(F(n,m)^2))+F(n,m-1))));
     end
 t(m) = (m-1)*dt;
 theta(n,m)=(n*q*l)-(w*t(m)/e2);
 Y(n,m) = ((e2*(psi*F(n,m)/(sqrt(Q/sigma))))*(2*(cos((sigma*tau)+theta(n,m)))))+((e2^2*((psi*F(n,m)/(sqrt(Q/sigma)))^2))*(miu+(2*delta*(cos(2*((sigma*tau)+theta(n,m)))))));
 end
 end
```